# Creating contour lines from DTM in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, contour, terrain

Is there any possibility to compute contour lines from a raster DTM directly in PostGIS on a PostgreSQL database?

I have only found this solution based on points "[Fast contour lines using plain PostGIS](https://abelvm.github.io/sql/contour/)", but none based on rasters.

Might it be possible to call `gdal_contours` from a SQl-function?

Comment: Well, a raster is really just points on a regular grid. So, you could easily convert your raster to polygons, using ST_Centroid(ST_DumpAsPolygons(..... and substitute that value for geomin in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a raster is just a regular grid, you could use the raster to polygon functions to convert your raster to polygons and feed these to the function in the link you provided. If you use [ST_DumpAsPolygons](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_DumpAsPolygons.html), adjoining cells with the same value will be merged, which means you will not have a regular grid, though the function in the link you provided copes with irregular polygons. However, if you want to create a regular polygonal grid, you can use the [ST_PixelAsCentroids](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_PixelAsCentroids.html) function to convert each raster to a point and a value, and then use ST_Expand to convert this point back to a square representing the size of your raster coverage, and then feed these to the function in your link above.

For example, using 2.5 in ST_Expand to represent a 5m x 5m raster cell:

```
SELECT 
    array_agg(foo.val), 
    array_agg(ST_Expand(foo.geom, 2.5)) 
 FROM 
      (SELECT (ST_PixelAsCentroids(rast)).* AS px 
         FROM some_rast) foo;
```

So given the function signature in the link you provide,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION contour_lines(
    IN geomin geometry[],
    IN colin numeric[],
    IN breaks numeric[]
)
```

this then becomes:

```
WITH inputs (geoms, vals, breaks) AS 
   (SELECT 
      array_agg(ST_Expand(foo.geom, 2.5)),
      array_agg(foo.val)::numeric[], 
      ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]::numeric[]
     FROM 
       (SELECT (ST_PixelAsCentroids(rast)).* AS px 
         FROM some_rast) foo)
)
SELECT contour_lines(geoms, vals, breaks) FROM inputs;
```

Arguably, a cleaner way of doing this would be too rewrite the linked function to take a raster coverage, but you get the idea.

Comment: This works, thanks a lot you gave me the missing piece!

Answer (score 1):

With version 3.2.0, you could do this using ST_Contour() (see https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Contour.html).